# Creating an NTFS truecrypt container in console on linux?

Tags: linux, command-line, ntfs, truecrypt

How do I create an ntfs truecrypt container? There isn't much documentation on commandline usage. I tried the following:

```
$ truecrypt -t -c mycontainer

// .. Go through options, selected 'None' when asked for filesystem

$ mkfs.ntfs -f -L myNTFS mycontainer
mycontainer is not a block device.
Refusing to make a filesystem here!
```

Comment: The documentation says "For information on command
line usage applying to the **Linux and Mac OS X versions**, please run: `truecrypt –h`"

Answer (score 2):

Here's what worked for me (though I used the GUI for most steps):

- Create a container of the desired size with any filesystem (I used FAT).
- Mount it using the TrueCrypt GUI.
- From a console window, run `mount`. Find the entry that corresponds to your Truecrypt container, and note down its device name. It should be something like `/dev/mapper/truecrypt1` (the last part of it should correspond to the name of your TrueCrypt volume). This is the 'raw device' for your volume against which you can do low-level operations such as `dd`, `mkfs` and the like.
- Now unmount the volume with `sudo umount /dev/mapper/truecrypt1` (replacing the path as needed).
- Format as NTFS: `sudo mkfs.ntfs -f -L SOME_LABEL /dev/mapper/truecrypt1`. Use a label of your own choice as `SOME_LABEL`, and be sure to use the correct device path (as above).
- Unmount the volume in TrueCrypt GUI (it will still show up as mounted).
- Mount it again.

Et voilà! You can verify it really is an NTFS volume by copying a large (>4 GB) file to it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are putting the horse before the buggy. You must create the partition and add the filesystem *before* encrypting it with truecrypt.

If you want to make a truecrypt *container* in linux, that's different. This is because a Truecrypt container is different than a NTFS filesystem that's encrypted with Truecrypt. Think of it as a Truecrypt partition instead of an NTFS partition.  Truecrypt is the go-between for the 'container' and the OS, linux in this case.

Comment: I wanted to create a truecrypt container that I could access from both a linux and windows environment. When going through the container creation options, I saw options for ext4, ext3, FAT, etc. The ext filesystem won't be recognized by windows, and FAT doesn't support files greater than a few gigabytes. It seems [possible to create an NTFS truecrypt container](https://code.google.com/p/cryptonite/issues/detail?id=34). I can't seem to figure that out through the console. A container is preferrable because I wouldn't have to mess with repartitioning my harddrive.

Comment: Well, that's a bit different, I figured that's what you wanted to do. The link you provided does what I suggested, the ntfs filesystem is already on the device and is merely being mounted as a truecrypt container *first*, which is correct. However, have you tried creating a truecrypt container on a Windows machine, then trying to open that in linux? that seems like an easy way if it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a file container sized 1GB, use:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=file bs=1M count=1000
```

and then you can use:

```
mkntfs -fF file
```

Under Linux TrueCrypt use the command:

```
truecrypt --help
```

and you have all options.